# MySQL user host networking

Tags: mysql

How is the host for a MySQL user evaluated by the database? My server tries to connect to the database from `myhostname` but fails even though I've set the hostname for that server in `/etc/hostname` It does work when I use an IP though.

The user was created like so:

```
GRANT ALL ON db.* TO 'dude'@'myhostname';
```

Comment: `/etc/hostname` is for the local machine, add myhostname to `/etc/hosts` to bypass dns lookup for an ip

Comment: have you done `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL error will tell you the hostname the server machine *thinks* your user is connecting from. Depending on DNS settings, this may or may not be the hostname your client thinks is assigned to itself. The name *as seen from the server* is the one you need to set in your `GRANT` statement.

(Which is logical. Suppose I know that the server gives privileges to host Alice. I have host Bob. Since it's *my* host, I can change its name to Alice. If just doing this granted me Alice's privileges, the whole `GRANT` scheme would be completely insecure! What happens is that my host thinks it's Alice, but the server sees my IP, asks the DNS "Who is this?" and receives "He's Bob". I still can steal Alice's privileges, but I need to [compromise the DNS records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking) somehow)

In a pinch, add the client IP and hostname to the server `/etc/hosts` file. This is a hack, however, and proper DNS setting is the way to go: a forgotten `hosts` hack might cost you a long time of head scratching a few months down the road.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [DNS Lookup Optimization and the Host Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/host-cache.html) from the MySQL manual:

> The server performs host name resolution using the thread-safe `gethostbyaddr_r()` and `gethostbyname_r()` calls if the operating system supports them. Otherwise, the thread performing the lookup locks a mutex and calls `gethostbyaddr()` and `gethostbyname()` instead.

Therefore the resolution of the connecting IP to `myhostname` is a matter for the operating-system, rather than MySQL.  You should first determine that your OS is correctly resolving the client IP and, if not, debug your OS or nameservice configuration (questions on this subject might be better directed to [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Sever Fault](http://serverfault.com), rather than StackOverflow).